# Possible causes for long blocking xhr on mac chrome?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I have a consistent extremely long (2min+) blocking call on mac/chrome. The same set of steps work just fine on other operating systems or browsers. (And even some other macs.) The site isn't super chatty, and there aren't any other requests that take anywhere over 2 seconds.

The blocking PUT call almost always follows a DELETE call to a different url. (Same server.) According to my console logs, the server actually receives and returns the results of the PUT call very quickly. So Chrome thinks it is blocked but it is actually already processed!

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this post: [Chrome and Firefox CORS AJAX calls get aborted on some Mac machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389410/chrome-and-firefox-cors-ajax-calls-get-aborted-on-some-mac-machines/20429014#20429014)

This mac had a DISABLED Sophos antivirus on the machine. Uninstalling it completely fixed this issue.

ARGGGGG.

Hopefully someone else finds this post and is able to spend less than the hours we spent on it.